# How to draw a chart from a CSV-file in MQL4?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance, mql4, metatrader4, forex

I'm new to **`MQL`** and **`MetaTrader 4`**,
but I want to read a **`.CSV`**-file and draw the values I've got into the chart of the **`Expert Advisor`** I'm working on.

Every `.CSV` file has the form of:

```
;EURUSD;1
DATE;TIME;HIGH;LOW;CLOSE;OPEN;VOLUME
2014.06.11;19:11:00;1.35272;1.35271;1.35271;1.35272;4
2014.06.11;19:14:00;1.35287;1.35282;1.35284;1.35283;30
```

Where the `EURUSD` part is the `_Symbol`, which another program generated, the `1` is the period, and all the other things are the data to draw.

Is there any form to do it inside an **`Expert Advisor`**, or do I need to use a **`Custom Indicator`**?

If that's the case, how can I do it in the simplest way?

<sub>P.S.: I read the data in a **`struct`**:</sub>

```
struct entry
{
  string date;
  string time;
  double high;
  double low;
  double close;
  double open;
  int volume;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There are three principally different approaches available in MT4

First,
 one may
**reshuffle** data-cells into a compatible format `T,O,H,L,C,V` and 
 **import** records using <kbd>**`F2`**</kbd> **`History Center`** `[Import]` facility of the MetaTrader Terminal. One may create one's own `Symbol`-name so as to avoid name-colliding cases in the `History Center` database.

This way, one lets `MT4` to create system-level illustrations of the **`TOHLCV`**-data, using the platform's underlying graphical engine.

[image]

---

Second,
<sub>one may ignore the underlying graphical engine and
work on a user-controlled GUI-overlay
so as to</sub> 
**implement** an algorithm to read a **`CSV`** file and 
**create** a set of `MQL4` GUI-objects algorithmically, based on the data contained in the said `CSV` file. An experience based decision whether to use an `{ ExpertAdvisor | CustomIndicator }` would yield to use a **`Script`** for this purpose, due to it's one-shot processing.
One shall realise, `MT4` code-execution ecosystem does a specific **context-binding** between an `MQL4`-code ( which is being run ) and an **`MT4.Graph`** which does not allow a code launched on a **`GBPJPY`** `MT4.Graph` to process directly objects, related with **`FTSE.100`** `MT4.Graph`. Yes, if asked to, one may implement a few add-ons and develop a sofisticated distributed processing model to make this work "accross" the said context-binding borders.

---

Third,
<sub>and for some cases the most interesting way is a file based approach, where</sub>
one may
**pre-process** `CSV` data in a similar way as in second option but not inside a live-`MT4` process, but "beforehand" and
**generate** one's own <kbd>**`Profile`**</kbd> file, keeping an `MT4` convention of placing & content of 
- `~/profiles/<aProfileNAME>/`**`chart01.chr`** 
- `~/profiles/<aProfileNAME>/`**`order.wnd`** 
-`~/profiles/`**`lastprofile.ini`**, referring **`<aProfileNAME>`** on it's first row

This way, once the `MT4` session starts, the pre-fabricated files are pilot-tape auto-loaded and displayed as one wishes to, **`Q.E.D.`**

A `.chr` file syntax sample:

```
<chart>
id=130394787628125000
comment=msLIB.TERMINAL: _______________2013.04.15 08:00:00 |cpuClockTIXs = 448765484 |
symbol=EURCHF
period=60
leftpos=6188
digits=4
scale=4
graph=1
fore=0
grid=0
volume=1
scroll=0
shift=1
ohlc=1
...

<window>
height=100
fixed_height=0

<indicator>
name=main

<object>
type=10
object_name=Fibo 16762
...

<object>
type=16
object_name=msLIB.RectangleOnEVENT
period_flags=0
create_time=1348596865
color=25600
style=0
weight=1
background=0
filling=0
selectable=1
hidden=0
zorder=0
time_0=1348592400
value_0=1.213992
time_1=1348624800
value_1=1.209486
ray=0
</object>
...

<object>
type=17
object_name=msLIB.TriangleMarker
period_flags=0
create_time=1348064992
color=17919
style=2
weight=1
background=0
filling=0
selectable=1
hidden=0
zorder=0
time_0=1348052400
value_0=1.213026
time_1=1348070400
value_1=1.213026
time_2=1348070400
value_2=1.210476
</object>
```

Comment: Please do not use comments to badger askers into accepting your answer. They are free to accept whatever answers they want, whenever they want. All of these comments have been removed.

Comment: Brad, **what reason do you have for** such a proposed **asymmetry?** If you promote one side's freedom to act, why do you restrict & censor the other side's freedom to ask? A bit Orwelish equality, isn't it? Quo bono pro?

Comment: Nagging is gauche. If you're gonna comment, [be educational](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298579/is-it-greedy-to-ask-newbies-to-not-forget-an-upvote-if-they-find-the-answer-us) not demanding.